# Run Joomla live site on local server

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.5

I'm trying  to run a copy of a joomla site (that works perfectly on the hosting) but, when I put all its files on my directory and install its BD just works administrator site but the site itself keeps in white screen.

I update its configuration file (configuration.php) exactly:

**-DB**

- User
- Password
- Host
- DB & DB prefix no changes needed

**-Logs**

- log_path = 'C:\wamp\www\sitename\logs'
- tmp_path = 'C:\wamp\www\sitename\tmp';

I don't know what to do, I don't understand (I'm new with Joomla)

**Joomla version:** 3.5.1
**PHP:** 7.0

Comment: Check the servers error log to see if you can find any error messages.

Comment: I activate error reporting "development" and display this error "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\timenetworks\plugins\system\xcalendar\xcalendar.php on line 56" ... I disable that plugin and there are not errors but still white screen. logs, does not show anything, just a wrong password event

Answer (score 1):

A white screen usually is a sign of a server error of any kind. A first step to identify the underlying problem is to enable the debug mode and set the error reporting to development. You should then get an error message instead of the white screen.

In general, it is a good idea to use a tool like Akeeba Backup to transfer sites. It takes care of some environmental differences between the production server and localhost. You can even utilise another database management system.

Comment: Thanks, It's an old site of a client so I don't want to make changes until this backup runs locally, It's my first time with Joomla. Please see my comment above.

Comment: You should have a backup anyway...
I've never encountered problems adding Akeeba Backup to a site. It is the best option you have.

Answer (score 0):

Its not much complicated.. As you said you have already configure DB, Prefix, Host and Password.

So verify it again and suggest to check your localhost PHP version and online PHP version. Its create problem if your PHP version and live PHP version are different.

And make sure the PHP libraries you used on live site, these all need to install on your local PC too.

and make error_reporting maximun to check exact error and tell me error you get.

Please do this and if still you have issue than please wirte comment me, we will find more about your issue.

Thank You.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I noted that extensions manager on "manage" is just listing three elements while live site shows 3 pages with elements. It is something that  not recognizing all the extensions, what could I check?

Comment: Actually I'm running with the same enviroment, php 5.6.33, apache 2.4.29 and mysql 5.5.5-10.1.30

Comment: Can you send me screen-shot of listing of local and live both ? if possible.